# Cross Platform App IBM Worklight

Tags: eclipse, cross-platform, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight MEAP for developing Cross Platform application but when I build my project I got following error

[2012-11-30 18:31:47] iphone build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Problem reading info.plist file /Users/ipcmac/Documents/workspace_IndigoNew/MYNew/apps/NewApp/iphone/native/MYNewNewAppIphone-Info.plist (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /Users/ipcmac/Documents/workspace_IndigoNew/MYNew/apps/NewApp/iphone/native/MYNewNewAppIphone-Info.plist (No such file or directory)

[2012-11-30 18:32:20] android build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Error while reading XML file: /Users/ipcmac/Documents/workspace_IndigoNew/MYNew/apps/NewApp/android/native/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /Users/ipcmac/Documents/workspace_IndigoNew/MYNew/apps/NewApp/android/native/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
[2012-11-30 18:32:20] A core eclipse exception has occurred: Failed to read project description file from location '/Users/ipcmac/Documents/workspace_IndigoNew/MYNew/apps/NewApp/android/native/.project'.

So any one have solution for this ????

Comment: It looks like some files are missing from your project. Have you validated that those files exist in the expected location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and delete the native folders under iPhone and Android and rebuild.